# Redirecting request from filter without entering into servlet?

Tags: redirect, servlets, request, response, servlet-filters

I am trying to redirect my requests to another server from filter and the following snippet is the part of redirection from filter

**Filter.java**

```
try {
 String redirectUrl = “https://abc.xyz.com/home”;
 response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
 return;
 } catch (Exception ex) {
 logger.log(Level.INFO, "====== thus the occured exception is ====== "+ex);
 }
```

**Servlet.java**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "------ entering into download servlet !");
res.getWriter().write("Processed download request");
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "------ completed processing the servlet !");
return;
}
```

**Expected** : Request would get redirected from the filter and will not enter into the servlet

**But what’s happening :**

- getting the debug logs within doGet() method
- Request returns "302 Found” status code and getting redirected

Is there any way the request gets redirected from the filter itself without entering into the servlet? How tomcat forwards the request from filter to servlet?

Comment: No one can reproduce your problem in a scratchpad project based on the information provided so far. Try reframing your question in such way that you can successfully reproduce the problem in a scratchpad project with everything else set to defaults or sane/logical values without ever looking into your own project.

Comment: @BalusC We could reproduce it when we just have a tomcat running over in our local machine. Just by adding a redirect part in the filter and just adding debugging log in our servlet.

Comment: That's what I have did...

Comment: Yes, but if we put the provided filter code unmodified in an **empty** `doFilter()` method of an **empty** test filter class mapped on a test URL pattern of `/*`, we still can't reproduce your problem. This means that you have omitted code contributing to the problem. This means that the provided code is not a [mcve] at all. This is unhelpful for us in order to help you.